# Spin tool issues with beveled pipe end

Tags: mesh

[image]I'm using the spin tool to create pipe. But at the end of the spin the pipe is beveled. How can I correct this? Also the pipe is not the same thickness through the pipe.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your scale is probably not 1:1:1, you need to apply the scale of your object in *Object* mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>).

Comment: Thank you so much. That did it!